# Outlier analysis methods and boxplot

Tags: python, data-analysis, boxplot, outliers

```py
z_score = (train_1['MonthlyRevenue'] - train_1['MonthlyRevenue'].mean()) / train_1['MonthlyRevenue'].std()

(z_score>3).sum(), (z_score<-3).sum()

upper = train_1[z_score<=3]["MonthlyRevenue"].max()

lower = train_1[z_score>=-3]["MonthlyRevenue"].min()

upper,lower

train_1_zscore_replaced = train_1.copy()

train_1_zscore_replaced["MonthlyRevenue"][z_score>3] = upper

train_1_zscore_replaced["MonthlyRevenue"][z_score<-3] = lower

train_1_zscore_replaced.head(30)
```

I have columns with 58 variables.

1- What can I do to show all columns in the boxplot for Outliers analysis?

2- How do I know which method (z-score, hard-edges, IQR ..) to choose for outlier analysis?

Data Set:
[1]: https://www.kaggle.com/jpacse/datasets-for-churn-telecom

Comment: Please share some of your data and what you have tried?

Comment: Do IQR * 1.5 + Upper Quartile to find upper boundary

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Grayrigel For example, I used the z-score method for the MonthlyRevenue variable. But it will take a long time to do this for 58 variables one by one. What can I do instead?
Also, how can I distinguish which method should I use for variables?

Comment: I am new here. Thank you @zabop

Comment: I am sorry. I should have been more specific. You have to add data in the text form because we can't extract data from images.

Comment: @Evorage I know the IQR calculation,thanks, but does it make sense to use IQR for every variable? How can I decide to use other methods?

Comment: @Grayrigel I added the link to the data set. I'm sorry. I'm just learning here.

Comment: No need to be sorry there. perhaps you can use IQR. Also, you can select all the `numerical` columns  `df = df[['MonthlyRevenue', 'MonthlyMinutes' .... ]] and make a boxplot using `sns.boxplot(data=df);plt.show()`

Comment: @Grayrigel Thank you so much ,I will try